# Parse - Setting device token

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to set a device token in parse. The official documentation gives the following code for doing this

**Official Documentation(objective C)**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
  // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
  PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
  [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
  currentInstallation.channels = @[ @"global" ];
  [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}
```

I have converted the code as below but receive an error.

**My code (Swift)**

```
func application( applcation: UIApplication!, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData! ) {
    println(deviceToken)

  let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()

            currentInstallation .setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
            currentInstallation .setObject(PFUser.currentUser(), forKey: "owner")
            currentInstallation .addUniqueObject("Test", forKey: "channels")
            currentInstallation .save()
```

I receive the following error when running my code:

```
 Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.
2014-11-13 03:44:01.306 Meetr[8855:2084537] Error: invalid type for key deviceToken, expected array, but got string (Code: 111, Version: 1.4.2)
sent
```

Can anybody help me as to why this is? I'm very confused as I have simply converted the original objective C code to swift.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In which line you are getting error?

Comment: Setdevicetokenfromdata that line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just set up my Parse notifications without any issues. The line where you have the error is exactly how I have mine, so I don't think that's what the problem is. Here's everything I have in App Delegate:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    //ENABLE PUSH NOTIFICATIONS
    let userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound)
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true

}

func application(application: UIApplication!, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData!) {
    //Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.

    let currentInstallation: PFInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    currentInstallation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
}

func application(application: UIApplication!, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: NSDictionary!) {
    PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
}
```

Comment: Thanks ClareHuxtable, I am going to go over this again tonight so hopefully this will allow me to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicated that the type is wrong:

```
Error: invalid type for key deviceToken, expected array, but got string (Code: 111, Version: 1.4.2)
```

Just change your data from String ("deviceToken") to Array (["deviceToken"]).

Comment: I find this strange though because that isn't what's done in the objective C version

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue was to begin with but, dropping the class and re-creating in parse appeared to fix it. Very strange..

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code for swift 3.0**

```
let installation = PFInstallation.current()
installation.setObject(Token, forKey: "deviceToken")

if(installation.badge != 0)
{
  installation.badge = 0
}
installation.saveEventually()
```

Comment: Where 'Token' is a String  value