# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken doesn't return deviceToken

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am registering for push notifications through Parse this way:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    Parse.setApplicationId("RfSGbVes0FGIX1sfxTEb3iybVsKgKPrfDuxco3vC", clientKey: "3pFBMar6vO6iUJouqTMt4VJVKZaXUc6p9RgHzTep")
    if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {
        let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector("backgroundRefreshStatus")
        let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")
        var pushPayload = false
        if let options = launchOptions {
            pushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil
        }
        if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || pushPayload) {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptionsInBackground(launchOptions, block: nil)
        }
    }
    let userNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.badge = 0
    println(installation.deviceToken) //deviceToken is nil
    let standardUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    standardUserDefaults.setObject(installation.deviceToken, forKey: "parseDeviceToken")
    standardUserDefaults.synchronize()
    delegate?.didFinishSettingToken()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)
}
```

When I run application I have a nil value from `println(installation.deviceToken)`

Maybe there is other way to handle `deviceToken`?

EDIT: If I stop application and run it again, it gives deviceToken. I don't receive `deviceToken` only when I run application first time.

Comment: you are running application in device?

Comment: yes, on iPhone 5, notifications are allowed.

Comment: Added an answer. may you get help from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:):

> *The first time you register your app’s preferred notification types, the system asks the user whether your app should be allowed to deliver
>   notifications and stores the user’s response. The system does not
>   prompt the user during subsequent registration attempts. The user can
>   always change the notification preferences using the Settings app.*

```
optional func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings)
{
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
```

Also you have to add

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotificationSettings(settings)
```

For iOS 7 and 8 version issues check this [tutorial](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/push-notifications-in-swift-for-ios-7-8).

Hope it helps.

Comment: When should I get deviceToken?

Comment: @NikitaZernov as per this answer you have to get devicetoken directly why you are getting it via installation.devicetoken ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/26954698/3202193 because device token is of current device